# Why "example link" doesn't work inside an unnumbered list?

Tags: support, markdown

This is the text of the message:

```
This X is an [example link](http://example.com/)

<ul>
<li>
This Y is an [example link](http://example.com/)
</li>
</ul>
```

And this is how it looks:

This X is an [example link](http://example.com/)

- This Y is an [example link](http://example.com/)

Update (this way it seems to work)

```
- This X is an [example link](http://example.com/)
```

- This X is an [example link](http://example.com/)

**But why not in unnumbered list?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the editor [help section on raw HTML](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#html) (emphasis mine):

[image: post editor html help]

> Block-level HTML elements have a few restrictions:
>
> 1. They must be separated from surrounding text by blank lines.
> 2. The begin and end tags of the outermost block element must not be indented.
> 3. **Markdown can't be used within HTML blocks.**

So, you either need to construct the `<a>` HTML yourself, or, more simply, use the Markdown syntax for unordered lists:

```
This X is an [example link](http://example.com/)

  - This Y is an [example link](http://example.com/)
```

...produces...

This X is an [example link](http://example.com/)

- This Y is an [example link](http://example.com/)

Comment: Markdown: Basics: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/basics. I thought that links are also part of `markdown`

Comment: They are, but you tried to combine raw block-level HTML with Markdown, which you can't do.

Answer (score 2):

Markdown [can't be used within HTML blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#html). Simply use [Markdown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-lists) to do the job.

This X is an [example link](http://example.com/)

- This Y is an [example link](http://example.com/)

That is:

```
This X is an [example link](http://example.com/)

- This Y is an [example link](http://example.com/)
```